# Missing Data in Query Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate

I've inherited a database from someone who has since left my office, and I'm having trouble correcting an issue that's come up with some of the data being pulled.

I've been able to narrow it down to the issue only being with the query that's used to pull data to aggregate how many entries there were for a business and the percentage of those entries.

Shown in this first two images, there is data for the General Returns and the NOC entries:

[NOC Entries]

[image: 1]

[General Returns]

[image: 2]

But when applying the same date range, no data comes up in the percentage calculation, when I believe there should be.

There are two query steps that make up how the percentage data is pulled. Step one pulls the following:

[Step 1]

[image: 3]

But step 2 only pulls a very small part of the data:

[Step 2]

[image: 4]

Here's the SQL Code for Part 1:

```sql
SELECT TBL_ACH_Customers.CUST_ACHName
     , TBL_ACH_Returns_and_NOCs_Transactions.ACHReturns_Type
     , COUNT(TBL_ACH_Returns_and_NOCs_Transactions.ACHReturns_Type) AS CountOfACHReturns_Type

FROM TBL_ACH_Returns_and_NOCs_Transactions 
RIGHT JOIN TBL_ACH_Customers
    ON TBL_ACH_Returns_and_NOCs_Transactions.CUST_ACHName = TBL_ACH_Customers.CUST_ACHName

WHERE (((TBL_ACH_Returns_and_NOCs_Transactions.ACHReturns_Date) 
        BETWEEN [Forms]![FRM_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages]![startdate] 
            AND [Forms]![FRM_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages]![enddate]))

GROUP BY TBL_ACH_Customers.CUST_ACHName
       , TBL_ACH_Returns_and_NOCs_Transactions.ACHReturns_Type

ORDER BY TBL_ACH_Customers.CUST_ACHName;
```

And Part 2:

```sql
SELECT QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.CUST_ACHName
     , QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.ACHReturns_Type
     , QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.CountOfACHReturns_Type
     , COUNT(TBL_ACH_Transactions.ACHTRAN_Amount) AS CountOfACHTRAN_Amount
     , SUM(TBL_ACH_Transactions.ACHTRAN_NumEntries) AS SumOfACHTRAN_NumEntries

FROM TBL_ACH_Transactions 
INNER JOIN QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1 
   ON TBL_ACH_Transactions.CUST_ACHName = QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.CUST_ACHName

WHERE (((TBL_ACH_Transactions.ACHTRAN_EffectiveDate) 
       BETWEEN [Forms]![FRM_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages]![startdate] 
           AND [Forms]![FRM_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages]![enddate]))

GROUP BY QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.CUST_ACHName
       , QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.ACHReturns_Type
       , QRY_ACH_RPT_Return_Percentages_Step_1.CountOfACHReturns_Type;
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, and feel free to ask questions if you need more information!

Comment: Only you know your data. Try digging into *one* customer account your think should be included in 2nd query and run other non-aggregated queries to check all its transactions and returns within date range and see if they align. Currently, 2nd query with `INNER JOIN` removes accounts that do not have any ACH transactions but may have ACH returns and NOC transactions.

Comment: BTW - look into using table aliases to cut down repeating long names in query.

Comment: Analyzing this type of issue usually requires direct examination of data and therefore question is not really suited to SO. Might try a forum where files can be attached to post for download.